# Ruby programming exercise to determine whether a string is a palindrome

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a programming exercise in Ruby to determine whether a string is a palindrome. Here is what I came up with:

```
# Write a method that takes a string and returns true if it is a
# palindrome. A palindrome is a string that is the same whether written
# backward or forward. Assume that there are no spaces; only lowercase
# letters will be given.
#
# Difficulty: easy.

def palindrome?(string)
    iterations=string.length/2
    is_palindrome=true
    i=0
    while i<iterations
        if string[i] != string[string.length-i-1]
            puts("string is not a palindrome")
            is_palindrome=false
        end
        i+=1
    end
    return is_palindrome 
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts("\nTests for #palindrome?")
puts("===============================================")
    puts('palindrome?("abc") == false: ' + (palindrome?('abc') == false).to_s)
    puts('palindrome?("abcba") == true: ' + (palindrome?('abcba') == true).to_s)
    puts('palindrome?("z") == true: ' + (palindrome?('z') == true).to_s)
puts("===============================================")
```

This returns the following:

```
Tests for #palindrome?
===============================================
string is not a palindrome
palindrome?("abc") == false: true
palindrome?("abcba") == true: true
palindrome?("z") == true: true
===============================================
```

The first output should be "false", and I can't figure out why it is not returning that. It does print "string is not a palindrome", so I would expect it to also set the "is_palindrome" variable to "false" and return that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as your solution is concerned, I think you are mistaken your code works as expected. Of course `false == false` is true, so `palindrome?("abc') == false is true`.

Although not directly related to your solution but how about using inbuilt `reverse` functionality of ruby

```
def palindrome?(string):
    string == string.reverse
end
```

Comment: Hi hspandher, thanks for your reply. Indeed I believe I misinterpreted the output; the code actually does work if they all return "true". (And yes, using .reverse gives the same result).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This answer doesn't answer your question, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36516468/676874) was faster.

If you want to test your code you should also use also unit tests.

An example:

```
# Write a method that takes a string and returns true if it is a
# palindrome. A palindrome is a string that is the same whether written
# backward or forward. Assume that there are no spaces; only lowercase
# letters will be given.
#
# Difficulty: easy.

def palindrome?(string)
    iterations=string.length/2
    is_palindrome=true
    i=0
    while i<iterations
        if string[i] != string[string.length-i-1]
            #~ puts("string is not a palindrome")
            is_palindrome=false
        end
        i+=1
    end
    return is_palindrome 
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.
require 'minitest/autorun'
class FirstLetterTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_abc
    refute(palindrome?('abc'), "'abc' is detected as a palindrome, but it isn't")
  end
  def test_abcba
    assert(palindrome?('abcba'), "'abcba' is not detected as a palindrome")
  end
  def test_z
    assert(palindrome?('z'), "'z' is detected as a palindrome, but it isn't")
  end
end
```

I removed your `puts("string is not a palindrome")` - it confuse the output.